# Setting methods permissions a quorum network

Tags: solidity, contract-development, quorum

I have 3 solidity smart contracts that run in a quorum network with 7 nodes.
At the moment i use the constructor to set the owner of the smart contract, that is the node that deployed it.

```
 constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
}
```

This allows me to consent the access of some methods with

```
require(owner == msg.sender);
```

Now, I would like to allow access to these methods also to two other nodes. Is it possible to set these permissions at run time? Or you suggest me to write the addresses of the allowed nodes directly in the code? If so, where do I find the quorum node addresses?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Quorum, then before going to much further, please consider reviewing our new permissions model here: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/pull/715 once you switch tot he branch, you can also see the permission system documentation as well that explains purpose and the intended use.

Comment: i don't understand how to use it

Comment: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/blob/973caccef534bbcc44d98249a87c0cc61bfb18cc/docs/Permissioning/Usage.md is the doc you should read.